# how to use assembly to get the result of a __stdcall function that returns float

Tags: c++, windows, x86, inline-assembly, stdcall

I have an assembly routine that calls, in a generic way, a function known to use the `stdcall` convention and return a `float`. This function is being used by a marshalling framework to expose `stdcall` functions to a scripting language.

## Background

Here's the function using GNU inline assembly that compiles on MinGW 4.3, Win32:

```
inline uint64_t stdcall_invoke_return_float(int args_size_bytes,
                                            const char * args_ptr,
                                            void * func_ptr)
{
    uint64_t result;
    assert(
        0 == args_size_bytes % 4
            || !"argument size must be a multiple of 4 bytes");
#if defined(__GNUC__)
    asm
    (
        /* INPUT PARAMS:  %0 is the address where top of FP stack to be stored
         *                %1 is the number of BYTES to push onto the stack, */
        /*                   and during the copy loop it is the address of */
        /*                   the next word to push */
        /*                %2 is the base address of the array */
        /*                %3 is the address of the function to call */
            "testl %1, %1    # If zero argument bytes given, skip \n\t"
            "je    2f        # right to the function call.        \n\t"
            "addl  %2, %1\n"
        "1:\n\t"
            "subl  $4, %1    # Push arguments onto the stack in   \n\t"
            "pushl (%1)      # reverse order. Keep looping while  \n\t"
            "cmp   %2, %1    # addr to push (%1) > base addr (%2) \n\t"
            "jg    1b        # Callee cleans up b/c __stdcall.    \n"
        "2:\n\t"
            "call  * %3      # Callee will leave result in ST0    \n\t"
            "fsts  %0        # Copy 32-bit float from ST0->result"
        : "=m" (result)
        : "r" (args_size_bytes), "r" (args_ptr), "mr" (func_ptr)
        : "%eax", "%edx", "%ecx" /* eax, ecx, edx are caller-save */, "cc"
    );
#else
#pragma error "Replacement for inline assembler required"
#endif
    return result;
}
```

This is just a little glue to make it easier to write test cases:

```
template<typename FuncPtr, typename ArgType>
float float_invoke(FuncPtr f, int nargs, ArgType * args)
{
    uint64_t result = stdcall_invoke_return_float(
        nargs * sizeof(ArgType),
        reinterpret_cast<const char *>(args),
        reinterpret_cast<void *>(f)
    );
    return *reinterpret_cast<float *>(&result);
}
```

Now I have some test cases that invoke this function:

```
__stdcall float TestReturn1_0Float()
{ return 1.0f; }

__stdcall float TestFloat(float a)
{ return a; }

__stdcall float TestSum2Floats(float a, float b)
{ return a + b; }

static const float args[2] = { 10.0f, -1.0f };

assert_equals(1.0f, float_invoke(TestReturn1_0Float, 0, args)); // test 1
assert_equals(10.0f, float_invoke(TestFloat, 1, args));         // test 2
assert_equals(-1.0f, float_invoke(TestFloat, 1, args + 1));     // test 3
assert_equals(9.0f, float_invoke(TestSumTwoFloats, 2, args));   // test 4
```

## Problem

Randomly, test 3 is giving me garbage output instead of returning -1.0.

I'm wondering if I'm

- failing to preserve some state before the `call` instruction?
- messing up some state with the `fsts` instruction?
- fundamentally misunderstanding how to get a `float` value from a `stdcall` function that returns `float`????

All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lacking a windows machine, I can't fully test this; on Linux, the following gets me the return code of a float function:

```
extern float something(int);

#include 
#include 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int val = atoi(argv[1]);
    float ret;

    asm("pushl %1\n\t"
        "call * %2\n\t"
        "addl $4, %%esp"
       : "=t"(ret)
       : "r"(val), "r"(something)
       : "%eax", "%ecx", "%edx", "memory", "cc");

    printf("something(%d) == %f\n", val, ret);
    return 0;
}
```

The key is the use of the `"=t"(ret)` constraint - that gets the *top of the floating point stack*, see [Machine Constraints](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) (from the gcc manual). If Windows `stdcall` returns `float` results in `ST(0)` as well, that should work, no need for `fld`/`fst` as the compiler can do those for you if necessary.

You also need to specify the `memory` and `cc` clobbers when you call functions from within inline assembly.

Comment: It seems to work consistently with the `=t` constraint. I would still like to know *why* using the `fsts` instruction works inconsistently, however! Also, why do I need the memory clobber?

Comment: The memory "clobber" is actually a _barrier_. It means the compiler will order the inline `asm()` block in such a way with the remaining instructions generated that all loads/stores have completed before it, and are re-done after it. Same for `cc`, regarding condition codes, aka state from previous comparisions (so it will not, say, do a `cmp` before the asm block and test for the result after it).

Answer (score 1):

You are permitting a memory reference for the function pointer, GCC is liable to construct a reference relative the stack pointer on the incorrect assumption that the inline assembly does not change it.

Comment: That's a  very good point; the disassembly would easily show whether that's the case. I don't think so though, in this case - because the compiler knows the code location for the function (that's a _compile/link time_ constant) but not the offset between that and the current stackpointer (that's a _runtime_ variable because the stackpointer varies depending on the calling context and/or calling thread). Stackpointer-relative _function addresses_ are ... unusual, since executing code located on the stack has been ... "deprecated".